# Can't use java libraries in kotlin project (Gson and Toasty)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gson

I'm trying unsuccessfully to work with the Gson and Toasty libraries in my kotlin project but android studio can't find their classes, what am I missing?

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'

}

android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "dev.gmarques.compras"
        minSdk 28
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments += ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            versionNameSuffix '.release'
        }
        debug {
            versionNameSuffix '.debug'
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildToolsVersion '33.0.0'
    namespace 'dev.gmarques.compras'
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-collections-immutable:0.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'

    // room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.3"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.3"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.4.3"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.3"
    // room

    implementation 'com.google.android.flexbox:flexbox:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10'  // ----------------------Gson
    implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.5.2' // ----------------------Toasty


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Class where i'm trying to use Gson and getting `Unresolved reference: Gson`

```
package dev.gmarques.compras

import dev.gmarques.compras.objetos.Categoria
import dev.gmarques.compras.objetos.CategoriaRv

 class Clone {
    companion object {

    fun categoriaParaCategoriaRv(categoria: Categoria): CategoriaRv {
        var jsonString = Gson().toJson(categoria)
        //return Gson().fromJson()

    }

}
```

}

Same happens to Toasty.

This is my first kotlin project so i'm sure i'm missing something but after some time spent i haven't been able to figure out what it is.

Comment: Perhaps you should `import com.google.gson.Gson`

Comment: Depending on your IDE, you may want to re-sync the project with the Gradle config. Then the IDE will likely suggest to import `com.google.gson.Gson`

Comment: @radof The IDE did not suggest automatic import and when I tried to import manually it did not recognize the library package

Comment: @Joffrey tried this, didn't work

Comment: If you manually add the import and fix the compile error of your function (because you don't return anything), does it compile correctly using gradle from the command line?

Comment: throws this error:
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
24 actionable tasks: 10 executed, 14 up-to-date
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.5.2.

Comment: did you add `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }` to the dependencies of the main build file?

Comment: @EmanuelMoecklin Yep

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like the problem with Gson was something wrong with the IDE, because once I restarted it, fixed the code compilation issues, synced gradle and did a `Build -> Clean Project/Rebuild Project`, it worked as expected.

Toasty on the other hand looks like it needs to be moved to another hosting service as discussed here: https://github.com/GrenderG/Toasty/issues/174

Thank's for your time